# Objective-C - Read-only variable is not assignable?

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I've been using the following code to move views around, and never had a problem.
I started using ARC in my project for the first time and I am getting the following error on the second line. "Read-only variable is not assignable"

Am I suppose to do this differently with ARC?

```
CGRect rect = self.frame;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
    rect.origin.x = 57;
    self.frame = rect;
}];
```

Comment: The code is perfectly legal. You should not encounter the error. Is there anything else you omitted that might have caused this problem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the CGRect inside an animation block.
Marking the variable with __block solved my problem

```
__block CGRect rect = self.frame;
```

Comment: You could also put the CGRect variable within the block itself, since you're only using it to modify `self`'s frame.  This would make the code easier to read.

Comment: Depends.... if self's frame changes *after* the animation starts, then doing what @ikuragames suggests would change the behavior of the code.   What araxt suggests is exactly the same behavior as what OP wrote in the first place.

Comment: I didn't place it in the block because it's being used outside of my block as well

Comment: @bbum you have to remember that the animation doesn't happen until the next iteration of the run loop.  Furthermore the OP has copied self.frame into a local CGRect, so modifying self.frame will have no effect on the meaning of the animation block.

Comment: @aryaxt - that's fair enough, the __block modifier does what you need it to do in this case. My point was more general though - readability of code is important. By making rect a block variable, it's not clear when the origin assignment actually happens. After you call animateWithDuration what do you expect rect to be? It won't be animated by UIView since UIView doesn't know anything about your rect. So has the assignment occurred, or does it happen after the animation completes, or ar the beginning of the next run loop? So both the actual behaviour and your desired behaviour are unclear.

Comment: All I was trying to do was to move the UIView when a tap is detected. The following code works as expected

Comment: Superb...Answer...Solve my problem within a minute.